# "Reference" Continuous Variable / Variables that are perfectly multicolinear and sum to 1

Tags: regression, linear, compositional-data

I am conducting an ecological study that has data on municipalities as a sample. In this data, I have bins with proportions of individuals within a certain category that resides there, for example, % of catholics, % of protestants, % of elderly, of children and of all ages by 5-year bins, % of females, etc, together with some other continuous variables such as population, wages. My dependent variable is a healthcare indicator at the municipal level, and it is considered that the demographic variables cited are all possibly causal for the indicator.

In my linear regression, how should I consider those continuous variables that sum to 100% (and are, therefore, perfectly multicolinear)? Is it correct to drop one of them (for example, proportion of people with college degrees, while keeping proportion of people with high school, and proportion of people with middle school degrees, or no degree at all), somewhat akin to what is done to dummy variables by dropping one and calling it the reference variable?If the above is indeed correct, how exactly do I interpret the model?

Comment: This is called compositional data, I added the tag. You could look at some of the upvoted posts in that tag!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Válmer. Have you looked at our posts about [compositional data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=composition*+data)?